# do not succeed to make pivot with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have built this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT [VendorCode], [VendorName], 
      year(CheckDate) as 'year',
      left(datename(month,CheckDate),3) as [month], 
      [CheckSum] as 'Amount'
   FROM ocho 
   WHERE [Canceled] ='N'
) as abc
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Amount)
  FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
) AS sumpivot
```

I get a table that each vendor is not be summarize to one row, each vendor is in 12 months or less, depends how many months we paid them in checks. I tried to make group by to the 
`vendorcode` and `name` and I get a failure.

Comment: I am struggling to understand your question - could you please edit the question and include the error you are getting, as well as what it is, you are needing assistance with?

Comment: What do you mean _I get a failure_?  Do you get an error?  Please edit your question with some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: guys, thank you very mach, you helped me so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think all works fine -

***Query:***

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      VendorCode INT
    , VendorName NVARCHAR(50)
    , CheckDate DATETIME
    , Canceled CHAR(1)
    , [CheckSum] DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (VendorCode, VendorName, CheckDate, Canceled, [CheckSum])
VALUES 
    (1, '1', '20100101', 'N', 4),
    (2, '2', '20100303', 'N', 2),
    (2, '2', '20100601', 'N', 1),
    (2, '2', '20100604', 'N', 99)

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
          [VendorCode]
        , [VendorName]
        , [year] = YEAR(CheckDate)
        , [month] = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CheckDate), 3) 
        , Amount = [CheckSum] 
    FROM @temp 
    WHERE Canceled = 'N'
) abc
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (
                jan, feb, mar, 
                apr, may, jun, 
                jul, aug, sep, 
                oct, nov, [dec])
) sumpivot
```

***Output:***

```
VendorCode  VendorName year   jan    feb   mar   apr   may   jun     jul   aug   sep   oct    nov    dec
----------- ---------- ------ ------ ----- ----- ----- ----- ------- ----- ----- ----- ------ ------ ------
1           1          2010   4.00   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
2           2          2010   NULL   NULL  2.00  NULL  NULL  100.00  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
```